# What is the meaning of ajaxify?

Tags: html, ajaxify

I've been hearing ajaxify for awhile now. However when  I tried google/youtube to have it explained to me better, I really cannot grasp the nuts and bolts about it. Like, is it something that makes my page load faster? It is? Why? Is is something that my html/php codes are converted into something by ajaxify to make my page faster to load? It is? Why?

Comment: It means to load content via ajax, where the content has been statically inside the HTML before.

Comment: Instead of reloading the entire page to get new information, "ajaxifying" refers to modifying the code to make HTTP requests via JavaScript to load and display new data without reloading the entire page.

Comment: You don't have to serve all your content at once. Instead you serve a smaller version of your page, which then gets enhanced in time or after user actions.

Comment: ...Like Stack Exchange does when new answers or comments are posted, or new votes are cast. This is all updated in the current open page without needing to reload everything

Comment: "without needing to reload everything", you mean by the time I hit the refresh button, I see that my page is being reloaded but what it actually does is that it just updates a portion of it?

Comment: I think I formulated an understanding: when you use ajaxify, it helps your page load just a portion of it. Other parts are somewhat "saved/cached". The reload takes effect only on the portions where changes triggered by the scripts have undergone.